# Numpy Array Multiplication with Transpose

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy Array

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0.5, 0.5]])
```

Now I want to calculate A^t*A, for which I thought of the following

```
np.dot(A.T,A)
```

What I want to get is an Array in form of

```
A_new = np.array([[0.0025, 0.0025], [0.0025,0.0025]])
```

But what I actually get is just a number

```
A_new = 0.005
```

How can I do this kind of array multiplication? Shouldn't 2x1 shape times 1x2 shape result in 2x2 shape?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. For me, the result of `A = np.array([[0.5, 0.5]])` followed by `print(np.dot(A.T,A))`.  Is there a chance that you have `A = np.array([0.5, 0.5])` (a one dimensional array) by mistake? If your question does reflect your code accurately, then it might be helpful if you would share the result of `np.__version__`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matmul`:

```
>>> np.matmul(A.transpose(), A)
array([[0.25, 0.25],
       [0.25, 0.25]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
result = A*A.T
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array - changed a bit to make the result a bit more interesting:

```
In [28]: A = np.array([[0.5, 0.25]])
In [29]: A.shape
Out[29]: (1, 2)
In [30]: A.T.shape
Out[30]: (2, 1)
```

Matrix multiplication

```
In [31]: A.T@A
Out[31]: 
array([[0.25  , 0.125 ],
       [0.125 , 0.0625]])
```

ELement wise, with broadcasting, does the same thing, since the `@` summation is on a size 1 dimension:

```
In [32]: A.T*A
Out[32]: 
array([[0.25  , 0.125 ],
       [0.125 , 0.0625]])
```

`A*A.T` is the same thing, but matrix multipication produces a (1,1):

```
In [33]: A@A.T
Out[33]: array([[0.3125]])
```

If `A` was 1d by mistake, you could get a scalar value

```
In [34]: A1 = A.ravel()
In [35]: A1.shape
Out[35]: (2,)
In [36]: A1.T.shape
Out[36]: (2,)    
In [38]: A1.T@A1
Out[38]: 0.3125
```

`dot` does the same thing:

```
In [39]: np.dot(A.T,A)
Out[39]: 
array([[0.25  , 0.125 ],
       [0.125 , 0.0625]])
In [40]: np.dot(A1.T,A1)
Out[40]: 0.3125
```