# Numpy product of a vector and it's transpose

Tags: python, numpy, transpose, simpsons-rule

I have a N x N complex NumPy array U_0 and I have to do manipulation with it :

[image: Simpson's rule]

First, how can I increase the array with zero efficiently ? I can simply copy it into an np.zeros((2N-1, 2N-1)) but maybe you guys know a better method. Thanks to Alexander Riedel for answer this question with the solution of numpy.pad

Second, I tried with

```
b = np.array([1,2,3])
```

I saw on previous post to transpose a 1D vector you can do

```
b_T = b[..., None]
# or
b_T = np.atleast_2d(b).T
```

but when I try `b_T.dot(b)` I get `shapes (3,1) and (3,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)`. I don't know how to get b into a shape of (1,3) instead of (3,).

Thanks

Comment: Numpy has a padding function: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

Comment: For padding from desired sides there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72042347/13394817). and for the second may be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72093105/13394817).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [expand_dims](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) function to do what you want. The problem here is that numpy does not consider a shape (3, 1) and a (3, ) equivalent. Alternatively look into the [`matrix` type](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

Filling the array with zeros, as the commenters pointed out is also the answer to your first question. If that is not efficient enough, look into using [sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) from scipy, maybe they have the features you're looking for.